# Le « grand manitou de [nom de société ] » : détails ?

Tags: étymologie, genre, origine-ou-raison, lexique, emprunts

La société *Netflix*<sup>1</sup> persiste à se permettre d'utiliser des images de tragédies pour fins de divertissement (mais étrangement on n'a pas choisi celles de [*9/11*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attentats_du_11_septembre_2001)). On [relate](https://www.tvanouvelles.ca/2019/01/19/birdbox-la-ministre-roy-ecrit-a-netflix) que le Québec répond qu'il n'a pas l'intention de se faire manger la [laine sur le dos](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dos/26513/locution?q=manger%20laine#154815) :

> Elle rappelle au **grand manitou** de Netflix que la [tragédie ferroviaire
>   de Lac-Mégantic](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accident_ferroviaire_de_Lac-M%C3%A9gantic) a fait 47 morts le 6 juillet 2013 [...]
>   (tvanouvelles.ca)

On parle du [PDG](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871474). On doit à *Samuel de Champlain* l'introduction du mot [*manitou*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manitou), d'[origine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/manitou) [*algonquine*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algonquin) (*manitu*, « grand esprit » ; de la langue des [Algonquins](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algonquins), peuple membre des [Premières Nations](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=algonquin&id=5335) du Canada), en français dans ses [*Voyages et découvertes faites en la nouvelle France, depuis l'année 1615 jusques à la fin de l'année 1618*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k8705145s/f228.image). On a une extension de sens par analogie et familièrement pour le « personnage important dont l'autorité, l'influence sont reconnues » (TLFi ; attesté en 1877 *Le Figaro* ; [possiblement](https://books.google.com/books?id=qtw4AAAAIAAJ&q=%22Datations%20et%20documents%20lexicographiques%22%20manitou&dq=%22Datations%20et%20documents%20lexicographiques%22%20manitou&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtgdPJ2frfAhUOnlkKHWPGCIUQ6AEIMDAB) avant, selon qu'on a avec ou sans *grand*).

---

- Le sens en langue algonquine étant celui de « grand esprit », l'apport de l'adjectif grand dans *grand manitou* fait-il double emploi généralement ; peut-on rappeler la mécanique de l'emprunt à cet effet et possiblement comparer avec un autre emprunt basé sur un nom composé ?
- Est-il courant de référer à un PDG ou à un chef d'entreprise par *(grand) manitou* et est-il plus courant d'avoir la majuscule initiale pour l'un ou les deux termes dans ce cas ; conçoit-on une gradation de sorte qu'on trouve applicable le terme *manitou* (sans *grand*) à un membre de la direction qui ne soit pas PDG ; en contexte que pense-t-on de *manitou en chef* pour le PDG ?
- Quel serait le [féminin](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3954) de *(grand) manitou* ; l'a-t-on déjà rencontré ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> ...dont la position dominante est au moins en partie [attribuable](https://www.lapresse.ca/techno/reseaux-sociaux/201812/19/01-5208600-facebook-a-laisse-des-geants-du-web-acceder-aux-donnees-de-ses-utilisateurs.php) à l'ingénierie de Facebook et à la concurrence déloyale envers les autres fournisseurs de contenus vu un vide juridique en partie colmaté [tout récemment](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/economie/quebec/201901/10/01-5210527-taxe-netflix-quebecoise-76-entreprises-etrangeres-ont-dit-oui.php) au Québec.</sub>

Comment: I don't know about the rest, but I think Minister Roy found the perfect French equivalent of (and perfect place to use) the English ["grand poo(h)bah"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Poobah) as it's "used as a mocking title for someone self-important ... who ...exhibits an inflated self-regard ... ."

Comment: @PapaPoule I think credit goes to the journalist, we only have quotes from the letter she addressed, and I'm actually quoting tvanouvelles.ca summarizing what she addresses in her letter. Sorry for not being exactly clear with _on relate que le Québec répond que_, I'm leveraging an idiom to summarize the tone more than the content. But thanks, I had never heard that expression, or I may have heard it without being able to understand at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Le sens en langue algonquine étant celui de « grand esprit », l'apport de l'adjectif grand dans grand manitou fait-il double emploi généralement ; peut-on rappeler la mécanique de l'emprunt à cet effet et possiblement comparer avec un autre emprunt basé sur un nom composé ?

L'algonquin étant peu étudié en France, personne n'y sait que *manitou* inclus déjà l'adjectif *grand*. On n'y rencontre quasiment jamais *manitou* seul, je n'ai jamais entendu que ***grand manitou***.

On retrouve un pléonasme similaire dans *[**loup-garou**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garou)*, l'étymologie de *garou* en ancien francique étant *werwolf* qui signifie *homme-loup*. Un *loup-garou* est donc un *loup-homme-loup*.

> Est-il courant de référer à un PDG ou à un chef d'entreprise par (grand) manitou et est-il plus courant d'avoir la majuscule initiale pour l'un ou les deux termes dans ce cas ; conçoit-on une gradation de sorte qu'on trouve applicable le terme manitou (sans grand) à un membre de la direction qui ne soit pas PDG ; en contexte que pense-t-on de manitou en chef pour le PDG ?

*Manitou* n'est plus utilisé qu'au sens figuré comme nom commun et *grand manitou* est donc le plus souvent écrit sans majuscule(s).

> Quel serait le féminin de (grand) manitou ; l'a-t-on déjà rencontré ?

On trouve quelques ***grandes manitoues***. Dans la première citation, il s'agit d'une entreprise, pas d'une personne :

> - La filiale du groupe PPR, **[grande manitoue](https://www.actualitte.com/article/monde-edition/elodie-perthuisot-nommee-directrice-du-livre-de-la-fnac/34127)** dans la distribution de loisirs et technologie en France, vient d'annoncer la nomination d'une nouvelle directrice au Livre.
> - Mais tu me conseillerais de commencer par quoi, Ô [**grande manitoue**](https://juneandcie.com/2016/05/13/a-loree-du-verger/comment-page-1/) ?