# Le sens et l'origine de « manie-tout » et son influence sur le « manitou » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, origine-ou-raison, lexique

Au TLFi on dit que l'extension de sens de [*manitou*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/manitou) pour « personnage influent » « a été peut-être favorisée par l'expression populaire *manie-tout* » (TLFi ; au DHLF on dit « probablement par calembour sur *manie-tout*. »). Je ne trouve pas ce terme au lexique.

---

- Qu'est-ce qu'un *manie-tout* (une personne qui *[manie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manier) tout*,
  mais encore ?) ; un *manie-tout* est-il un « personnage influent » ?
- D'où vient cette expression et depuis quand ?
- Quel serait l'apport du calembour ou de l'expression : est-ce au sens
  ou à la fréquence ou les deux ?

Answer (score 2):

La similarité sonore entre *manitou* et *manie-tout* est fortuite - en effet, *manitou* viens de l'algonquin *manitu*. Il dénomme un pouvoir surnaturel qui peut s'incarner dans une personne ou dans un objet. Par méconnaissance des anthropologues, on pensait jadis que le *manitou* était un dieu unique (appelé *grand manitou*).

Par une extension, on peut désormais utiliser *manitou* pour décrire une personne très influente, avec un certain degré d'ironie.

> *Elon Musk est le grand manitou de l'industrie technologique*: on décrit comment Elon Musk est un personnage important et central dans cette industrie, mais la dénomination *grand manitou* dénote une certaine critique de l'admiration aveugle qu'il suscite de la part de milliers de personnes.

Comment: Merci, oui je comprends (voir [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33506/3177) où on traite du _manitou_), mais qu'est-ce qu'un _manie-tout_, d'où vient cette expression ; en troisième lieu vous semblez dire ni l'un ni l'autre : svp. préciser ?

Comment: Un jeu de mot avec manitou. Ce mot n'existe pas dans le langage courant. D'après la construction de ce mot, il me semble qu'il dénote quelqu'un qui manipule les autres afin d'inspirer un culte de leur part.

Comment: Merci, mais que manie-tout existe ou non en langage courant n'est pas la question. On peut vouloir savoir ce que veut dire quelque chose indépendamment, et c'est la question...

Comment: Ce n'est pas que manie-tout n'existe pas en language courant, c'est plutot qu'il n'existe pas du tout.  Apres les etymologies fantaisistes viennent comme elles veulent, mais ca ne les rend pas plus exactes